# A problem on stable flat principle bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In B. Anchouche and I.Biswas's paper " Einstein-Hermitian connections on polystable principal bundles over a compact K\"ahler manifold" Page 209 there states that:

A principal $G$-bundle $E_G$ over a compact K\"ahler manifold is called stable if for every maximal parabolic subgroup $P\subset G$ and every reduction of structure group $\sigma :U\rightarrow E_G /P$ over some open subset $U$ with $co\dim(M\setminus U)\geq 2 ,$ there holds $\deg \sigma^*(T_{\text{rel}})>0,$ where $T_{\text{rel}}$ is the relative tangent bundle for the natural projection $E_G /P\rightarrow U.$

However, when I read Kevin Corlette's well-known work "Flat G-bundles with Canonical metrics" Page362, there is another definition of flat stable principal $G$-bundle

"we call a flat bundle stable if the image of its holonomy homomorphism is not contained in a proper parabolic subgroup of $G$" where $G$ is a complex semisimple algebraic group. Maybe this is a explicit result.

Do the above two definitions coincide for flat principal $G$ bundles?  I appreciate any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, There is another definition:   A principal $G$-bundle $E_{G}$ over a compact K\"ahler manifold $M$ is called stable if for every maximal parabolic subgroup $P\subset G$ and every reduction of structure group $\sigma : U\rightarrow E_G /P$ over an open subset $U$ with codimension($M\setminus U$) $\geq 2$, there holds $deg \sigma^*(T_{rel})>0 $, where $T_{rel}$ is the relative tangent bundle. Are the two definitions equivalent? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, it is a good idea. Thank you for your suggestion